# Updating width of uilabel when subview not

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell` whose neighboring subview is `UIControlSwitch`. When the `UIControlSwitch` is hidden, the `UILabel's` width is expected to grow. Below is my custom class implementation:

```
    - (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
  {
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
  }

   - (void)layoutSubviews
  {
     [super layoutSubviews];

     [self.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
     [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

     self.numberLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.numberLabel.frame);
     self.quoteLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth =    CGRectGetWidth(self.quoteLabel.frame);
 }

   @end
```

I have uploaded a sample [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg6mfig26e2f2ti/DynamicTableViewCellHeight-master.zip?dl=0) to explain the constraints on the storyboard.

The `UILabel's` width is not changing. If I set a trailing space between the `UILabel` and the `UIControlSwitch`, the control is partially hidden beyond the screen bounds. Hence the constraint for the `UILabel` has trailing space to the superview instead of the `UIControlSwitch`.

Comment: you have added constraints to UILabel- Remove horizontal space constraint and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hide a view, it still takes part in the layout process. So simply hiding your UISwitch will not cause anything to change.

So you either have to add/remove constraints, remove the UISwitch from its containing view or change how you are doing the constraints.

### Option 1: Instead of hide/show do remove/add.

If you put the UISwitch in its own view, you can pin the UILabel to the switches containing view. Instead of hiding the UISwitch, remove it from its containing view. The result will be that the containing view collapses and your UILabel will stretch as long as the label is pinned to the switches view and the switches view to the edge.

Instead of show, add the UILabel back into the container view. The view will stretch and your UILabel will shrink.

### Option 2: Use simple trailing constraint for UILabel.

Make your UILabel have a trailing constraint to the superview and CTRL drag that constraint into your code so you can set its value. Or you could add it manually if that is what you are doing.

Do not pin the UILabel to the UISwitch at all. Pin the UILabel to the right h§and side so it has the required position.

So your UILabel is now pinned to the right edge with an offset of your choosing. If you set this small, the UILabel will be over/under the switch. If set to the width of the switch plus left and right margin it will appear to stretch up to the switch.

In your code, you can find the width of the UISwitch by looking at its frame.

1) When the UISwitch is to be visible, set the trailing pin constraint of the UILabel to be the margin you want + width of UISwitch + margin to left of UISwitch you want.

2) When the UISwitch is to be hidden, set the trailing pin constraint of the UILabel to be the margin you want to the superview.

This should then cause the UILabel to extend to the switch when not hidden, or to the edge when the switch is hidden.

Comment: For option 1: When you say containing view, do you mean that I should another view to contain the UISwitch? When you say 'label is pinned to the switches view', do you mean horizontal spacing between the label and the switches view?

Comment: Yes. Add a view to hold your UISwitch. The purpose being to make it easy to remove it and add it back. By pin I mean horizontal spacing as you suspected. So add constraints from the UILabel trailing to the new view and from the view trailing to its superview (the edge). You could also center the new view vertically in its container if you want the UISwitch in the middle of the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. what would be the expected frame of the switch containing view? should it wrap the uicontrolswitch? or the frame of the cell?

Comment: The view is just to hold the UISwitch. If you use storyboard you can actually select the switch then on the xcode menu select Editor -> Embed In -> View. This will put it in a view for you. Then update the constraints.

Comment: This constraint setup you suggested, forces me to update the width of the UILabel to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: In Option 1: As long as the UILabel has leading horizontal constraint to its superview and trailing horisontal constraint to the switch view, you should not need to set a width as it will stretch to fill the area not taken up by the switch. In option 2: the width is controlled by the trailing horizontal constraint. Again assumption is the UILabel has a leading horizontal constraint pinning its left hand side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77592/discussion-between-rory-mckinnel-and-siddharthan-asokan).